# Android studio one usage was filtered out

Tags: android, android-studio

Since today I have this message when I want to check all usages of my variable "1 usage was filtered out"

[image]

I would like to see where I'm assign value to variable like I was doing before.
How can I remove this filter ?

Comment: File -> Invalidate Caches -> Restart -> Click at Invalidate and Restart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Wini the error disappear when you do this

```
File -> Invalidate Caches -> Restart -> Click at Invalidate and Restart
```